# How to turn off tensorflow XLA?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

XLA cannot run with multi GPU. How to turn it off so i can use normal gpu?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow-gpu. That does not help.

Comment: Could you. please, be a bit more precise and define " cannot run "?

Comment: Same problem here.  Somehow XLA got turned on. Now my tensorflow programs that ran on my gpu no longer run on the gpu, just the cpu. Did anyone ever find a solution?